# Regexp for URL validation

Tags: c++, regex, http

I am writing my own http server. Checking and validating headers and values ​​from requests, oddly enough, is one of its tasks. I found a [page](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex)
with a table comparing different regular expressions and decided to use one of them:

```
_^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$_iuS
```

then i went to https://regex101.com and tried to test it.
After some changes:

```
^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$
```

if passes my "test":

```
http://userid:password@example.com:8080
http://userid:password@example.com/
http://example.com/blah_blah
http://example.com/blah_blah_(wikipedia)
http://userid:password@example.com/
http://example.com/blah_(wikipedia)_blah#cite-1
http://example.bar/?q=Test%20URL-encoded%20stuff
http://example.bar?q=Spaces should be encoded
http://a.b--c.de/
```

But i need it inside my c++ server, so i again modified it :

```
std::regex re(
               "^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\\/\\/)(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\\.\\d{1,3})"
               "{3})(?!127(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\\.254(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})(?!"
               "192\\.168(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\\.(?:1[6-9]|2\\d|3[0-1])(?:\\.\\d{"
               "1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2["
               "0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\\.(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))|(?"
               ":(?:[a-z\\x{00a1}-\\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\x{00a1}-\\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?"
               ":\\.(?:[a-z\\x{00a1}-\\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\x{00a1}-\\x{ffff}0-9]+)"
               "*(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\x{00a1}-\\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\\d{2,5})?(?:\\/[^\\s]*)"
               "?$");
```

with edition above my compiler warns: `invalid hexadecimal number` and if i run i get

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  Unexpected end of regex when ascii character.
```

the error as said in that warning is in `\\x{00a1}-\\x{ffff}` but I don't know regex well enough to fix that. Please help, thank you.

Comment: You need to replace all ``\\x{XXXX}`` with ``\\uXXXX``. You can also replace ``\\/`` with `/` and ``[^\\s]`` with ``\\S``. Next time select a more appropriate regex flavor (C++ uses ECMAScript by default, not PCRE).

Comment: a [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) will make your life easier

Comment: The pattern is rather poor: `(?::\S*)?` at the beginning is redundant, it can be removed, and the `(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*` part will cause catastrophic backtracking, the `?` must be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace all `\x{XXXX}` with `\uXXXX` since ECMAScript regex flavor does not support `\x{XXXX}` notation. Next time you use regex online testers, make sure you select the appropriate regex flavor (C++ uses ECMAScript by default, not PCRE).

Next, you can also replace `\/` with `/` (you only need `\/` at the online regex tester when `/` chars are used as regex delimiters, or in languages where regexps are defined with the help of regex literals that are delimited with `/`), and you may shorten `[^\s]` to `\S`.

Next, `(?::\S*)?` close to the beginning of the pattern is redundant, it can be safely removed, and the `(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*` parts in the regex will cause catastrophic backtracking. To avoid it, the `?` quantifier after `-` must be removed.

So, the pattern you want to use is

```js
^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/\S*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ssz8Te/1/).

Now, this is how you can use it in the code:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::regex r(R"(^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/\S*)?$)");
    std::vector<std::string> lst;
    lst.push_back("http://userid:password@example.com:8080");
    lst.push_back("http://userid:password@example.com/");
    lst.push_back("http://example.com/blah_blah");
    lst.push_back("http://example.com/blah_blah_(wikipedia)");
    lst.push_back("http://userid:password@example.com/");
    lst.push_back("http://example.com/blah_(wikipedia)_blah#cite-1");
    lst.push_back("http://example.bar/?q=Test%20URL-encoded%20stuff");
    lst.push_back("http://example.bar?q=Spaces should be encoded");
    lst.push_back("http://a.b--c.de/");
    
    for (auto s : lst) {
        if (std::regex_match(s, r)) {
            std::cout << "MATCH: " << s << '\n';
        } else {
            std::cout << "NO MATCH: " << s << '\n';
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output of the program:

```cpp
MATCH: http://userid:password@example.com:8080
MATCH: http://userid:password@example.com/
MATCH: http://example.com/blah_blah
MATCH: http://example.com/blah_blah_(wikipedia)
MATCH: http://userid:password@example.com/
MATCH: http://example.com/blah_(wikipedia)_blah#cite-1
MATCH: http://example.bar/?q=Test%20URL-encoded%20stuff
NO MATCH: http://example.bar?q=Spaces should be encoded
NO MATCH: http://a.b--c.de/
```